# Splitting Overlapping Hours and minutes through java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have two ArrayList which has the date time which contains entry and exit say

EntryTime                        ExitTime

---

1. '2018-10-04 07:00:00'         '2018-10-04 11:00:00'
2. '2018-10-04 08:00:00'         '2018-10-04 08:30:00'
3. '2018-10-04 09:00:00'         '2018-10-04 09:40:00'
4. '2018-10-04 10:00:00'         '2018-10-04 10:30:00'

Entry-Exit data is in first ArrayList and data from 2 to 4 is another ArrayList.

Now, the entry-exit which you see at the top 1, I need to bifurcate that time because that is a manual entry made to the system which I am storing in the first array and the rests are system generated which are in the second array. so from 2 till 4, I cannot alter the data which is correct. I need to alter only the first record which is a manual entry. I need to make them distinct and non-overlap and my final result will be like this:

```
   EntryTime                     ExitTime
```

1. **'2018-10-04 07:00:00'         '2018-10-04 07:59:00'**
2. '2018-10-04 08:00:00'         '2018-10-04 08:30:00'
3. '2018-10-04 09:00:00'         '2018-10-04 09:40:00'
4. '2018-10-04 10:00:00'         '2018-10-04 10:30:00'
5. **'2018-10-04 08:31:00'         '2018-10-04 08:59:00'**
6. **'2018-10-04 09:41:00'         '2018-10-04 09:59:00'**
7. **'2018-10-04 10:31:00'         '2018-10-04 11:00:00'**

The bolded DateTime(5 to 7 i.e in the result section) is now made distinct and non-overlapped whereas the data in the first section is the same from 2 to 4. The changed values are from 5 to 7.
I am not able to think for should I loop through the ranges and cut the time.
Please help and tell me if you need any other information.
I searched enough but could not find the required answer or it could be I failed to understand.

Comment: Are the 2-4 entries sorted chronologically?

Comment: Use half-open intervals and avoid the `:59`. Let 07:00 to 08:00 mean from 07:00 inclusive to 08:00 *exclusive* so it doesn’t overlap with the next interval, from 08:00 to 08:30.

Comment: @wdc yes, i am sorting all the records based on their datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 2-4 entries are sorted chronologically you could just loop through the system generated entries, and for the `i-th` position, you could check if there is a gap between the `i-th` (the current entry) exit date and the `i+1-th` (the next one) entry date, and if there is, then check the other `ArrayList` to see if there is an entry that begins before and ends after the "gap" you found in the system generated `ArrayList`.

Pseudocode:

```
for(int i=0; i<arrayList2.size()-1; i++){

  if(arrayList2[i].exitDate is_before arrayList2[i+1].entryDate){

    fillTheGapIfPossible(arrayList2[i], arrayList2[i+1]);

  }

} 

fillTheGapIfPossible(entry1, entry2){

  for(int i=0; i<arrayList1.size(); i++){

    if(arrayList1[i].entry is_before entry1.exitDate &&
       arrayList1[i].exitDate is_after entry2.entryDate){

         makeNewEntry(entry1.exitDate, entry2.entryDate);

    }

  }

}
```

Where `arrayList2` is the system generated list.

Comment: in loop check, should the if condition be  if(arrayList1[i].entry is_before entry1.exitDate && arrayList1[i].exitDate is_after entry2.entryDate) instead of is_before in both the places.

Comment: Hi buddy, I am using the same logic but I am failing to bifurcate the last time when system data ends like in the output number 7. Since I have kept two lists, it is taking the intermediate gaps but missing the last one. Can u dry run the list and see why this is happening. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for this late follow back but I was able to solve this and of course by referring to your pseudo code too. Thanks a ton!!